# Setting function pointer inside class

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to create a simple windows api.

I need a little help in setting a function pointer in side class
Im getting errors trying to set the function to a function that is inside a class, Is there anyway this can be done without using static in the class?

```
class Window
{
public:
    WIN_API Window();

    struct WIN_API
    {
        bool(*OnMouseClick)(Vector2D position, MouseButton button);
        bool(*OnCreate)();
    }Event;
};

class MainWindow : public Window
{
public:
    MainWindow() : Window()
    {
        //error here
        this->Event.OnCreate = OnCreate;
        this->Event.OnMouseClick = OnMouseClick;
    }

    bool OnCreate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool OnMouseClick(Vector2D position, MouseButton button)
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects instead of function pointers.

Comment: you need use *virtual* functions here - say pure virtual in base class  *Window* and overwrite it in *MainWindow*

Comment: @RbMm i didnt really want to use virtual functions, I wanted to be able to create windows out side of a class as well.

Comment: you can of course write someting like `bool(Window::*OnCreate)();` in base class and `Event.OnCreate = static_cast<bool(Window::*)()>(&MainWindow::OnCreate);` in derived. and call like `MainWindow mw;(mw.*mw.Event.OnCreate)();` but this is very ugly and think error do this. need use *virtual* functions

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the member function of a particular instance.  This is best done using a lambda and `std::function` objects.

```
class Window
{
public:
    Window();

    struct WIN_API
    {
      std::function<bool(Vector2D, MouseButton)> OnMouseClick;
      std::function<bool()> OnCreate;
    } Event;
};

class MainWindow : public Window
{
public:
    MainWindow()
    {
      this->Event.OnCreate =
        [this] () { return this->OnCreate(); };

      this->Event.OnMouseClick =
        [this] (Vector2D position, MouseButton button)
        { return this->OnMouseClick(position, button); };
    }

    bool OnCreate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool OnMouseClick(Vector2D position, MouseButton button)
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: is it possible to have a template function that calls that lambda function, and would it make my code slower calling functions in a class that way?

Comment: Yes, a lambda is just an anonymous struct with a call operator.  You can use it anywhere.  If it makes your program slower I cannot say.  However, virtual functions seem more appropriate here.